# Spring-boot :A prototype scope bean: How to check if a bean with the same values already exists?

Tags: spring-boot, javabeans

So we have a stateful prototype scoped bean in spring-boot that has a few variables( its for JDBC repo essentially with differing database url and passwords)

How can we make the following use case work?

we want to use a bean with the 3 values x,y and z

Check if a bean already exists with the values x,y and z, if it does, retrieve the same instance of that bean. If it doesnt, create it and add it to the context

Answer (score 0):

I do not think prototype scope does compare the state of the bean. You might probably need to use a custom scope. Should you follow the example, use a key based on the state of the object to be initialized. Hope this helps!

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-custom-scope